# FacebookRedirectLoginHelper page - what page should it redirect to?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-login

I'm upgrading my php sdk for Facebook login for my web app and PhoneGap Build Android and iOS versions of it too, and am misunderstanding which page (and what should be on that page) to redirect to using...

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'example.com/XXXXX' );

My process: I use the js sdk to get the accesstoken once the user is logged in to Facebook, and then I send this access token to my server to store in the database for future server calls.

Is example.com/XXXXX the page that has all the code such as..?

```
// start session
session_start();
// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'xxx','yyy' );
// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'example.com/app/' );
// see if a existing session exists
if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_POST['fb_token'] ) ) {
// create new session from saved access_token
$session = new FacebookSession( $_POST['fb_token'] );
// validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
try {
if ( !$session->validate() ) {
$session = null;
}
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
// catch any exceptions
$session = null;
}
}
```

Thanks for you time and help.

Answer (score 0):

That page script should look like this:

```
// start session
session_start();
// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'xxx','yyy' );
// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'example.com/app/' );
try {
        $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect(); // returns a FacebookSession or null
    } catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {

        echo '<br>FB error: ' . $ex->getMessage() . '<br>';
    } catch(\Exception $ex) {

        echo '<br>Internal error: ' . $ex->getMessage() . '<br>';
    }
```

I keep this script in a controller method and after storing the token I use a redirect.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Mirceac. I'm still lost as to what page should go in example.com/app/ - is it the same page that the above script is on?

Comment: Also, if I'm retrieving the token from js in the first place ie from the js in the Phonegap native app, don't I need to send that token to php via POST, and inject that token in via $session = new FacebookSession( $_POST['fb_token'] ); ?

Comment: If you are already using js sdk to get the access token and reate a session then you should use "FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper" (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper/4.0.0) to get the session.

Comment: I you are using js login then http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-php-sdk-4-0-tutorial/ this tutorial might help you with getting the session from js. if you want to implement a php login then take a look at this one https://www.webniraj.com/2014/05/01/facebook-api-php-sdk-updated-to-v4-0-0/ .

Comment: Thank you Mirceac21. One question - why do you have to use "FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper" - why not just do $session = new FacebookSession( $_POST['fb_token'] ), as it's working. I'm not seeing what benefits there are doing it the other way. Cheers.

Comment: FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper it is a helper class that gives you the possibility to create a session using data from the cookies created by the JavaScript SDK. You do not have to make an ajax call to pass the session data to php when use js login. The first tutorial gives more details about this helper class.

Comment: If you send data to php with ajax at login then there is no point to use this helper class. Good luck!!

Comment: Thank you Mircac21 - that cleared it up beautifully!